# Вертикальное выравнивание изображения-ссылки

Tags: html, css

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу выравнять первый элемент ***Логотип*** по вертикали. Пытался уже применять свойства `vertical-align, lign-height`, но все безуспешно. Буду признателен тем, кто поможет разобраться с данной проблемой

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 10000px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

header {
  height: 86px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.HeadInfo {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Logo {
  height: 86px;
}

.Logo>#LogoLink {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1689173/fdc7c8e4-0329-4d04-bfcb-d34e53e740bd/s1200?webp=false);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
HTML код:

<header>
  <div class="HeadInfo">

    <div class="Logo">
      <a href="#" id="LogoLink"></a>
    </div>

    .....Остальной код шапки....

  </div>
</header>
```

Красный прямоугольник это не border. Я добавил его в при редактировании скриншота, чтобы было лучше видно шапку.

[image: Шапка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с flex:

```css
.Logo{
    height: 86px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```